# No puedo usar set en un Text en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text, set

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un programa el cual se conecta a una base de datos que guarda informacion de diferentes paises del mundo, una de las funciones del programa es la de "mostrar_pais" la cual deberia justamente mediante .set mostrar la informacion de los paises en el Text. Intente usando StringVar() en la variable "text_mostrar" y no me tiraba error, pero tampoco me mostraba la informacion de los paises y ademas no me dejaba usar la Scrollbar ya que me tiraba un error(por eso la comente) La informacion se deberia mostrar al presionar el boton.

```
import tkinter as tk
import mysql.connector

root = tk.Tk()

# frames
fframe = tk.Frame(root)
fframe.pack()

# conexion bbdd

cnn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", 
passwd = "password", database = "bbddejercicio")

##############MOSTRAR PAIS##############

def mostrar_pais():
    cur = cnn.cursor()
    sql = f"SELECT * FROM countries"
    cur.execute(sql)
    datos = cur.fetchall() 
    text_mostrar.set(datos)
    cur.close()

# labels
label_mostrar = tk.Label(fframe, text = "Mostrar paises:")
label_mostrar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "w", padx = (20, 0))

label_mostrado = tk.Label(fframe, text = "Paises en la bbdd")
label_mostrado.grid(row = 0, column = 3, pady = (20, 0))

# text
text_mostrar = tk.Text(fframe, width = 15, height = 5)
text_mostrar.grid(row = 0, column = 2, pady = (20, 0))
text_mostrar = tk.StringVar()

# button
button_mostrar = tk.Button(fframe, text = "Mostrar", command = mostrar_pais)
button_mostrar.grid(row = 1, column = 2, ipadx = 35, pady = (0, 20))

# scrollbars
# scrolly_mostrar = tk.Scrollbar(fframe, command = text_mostrar.yview)
# scrolly_mostrar.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = "nws", pady = (20, 0))
# text_mostrar.config(yscrollcommand = scrolly_mostrar.set)

# scrollx_mostrar = tk.Scrollbar(fframe, command = text_mostrar.xview)
# scrollx_mostrar.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = "nwe")
# text_mostrar.config(xscrollcommand = scrollx_mostrar.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el widget `tk.Text` no tiene un método `set` ni acepta `textvariables`, `Text` si tiene un método `insert` que lo podemos usar de esta forma:

La función que esta asignada al botón le agregamos estas linea de código

```
def cambiar_texto():
    text_mostrar.insert(tk.END, "texto)
```

con `tk.END` le indicamos que agregue el texto al final del ultimo texto agregado con anterioridad si es que lo hubiera, si no hubiera texto en el widget se agregaría al principio.

Para eliminar el contenido del `Text` podemos usar su método `delete` este método recibe dos parámetros de tipo `float` el índice que le indicara desde donde quieres que borre, y el segundo que indica hasta donde.

```
def borrar_texto():
    text_mostrar.delete(0.0, END) # END indica que queremos borrar hasta el ultimo carácter.
```

Para la `ScrollBar` primero creamos un `Frame` y lo posicionamos

```
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
```

widget `Text`

```
text_mostrar = tk.Text(frame, width=15, height=5)
text_mostrar.pack(side=LEFT) # Lo posicionamos a la izquierda
```

luego creamos la `ScrollBar` y se la pasamos al `Frame`

```
sb = tk.ScrollBar(frame)
# side = que este pegado a la derecha
# fill = le indicamos que ocupe todo el alto del widget
sb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)
```

A continuación realizamos las configuraciones del widget `Text` y `ScrolBar`

```
text_mostrar.config(sb.set) # le asignamos la Scrollbar al widget Text
sb.config(command=t.yview) # le indicamos que se posicione en el eje y del widget Text
```